# Easier way to correct Twitter statistics

Tags: twitter

I used a mass deletion site to get a fresh start on Twitter about five years back and now, when I finally started tweeting, I noticed that my tweet count is a bit wrong and my first tweet after my hiatus (one with #myFirstTweet) has disappeared. Other than that, everything seems fine.

The only action I've taken before starting my new tweets was removing all 3rd party apps like the deleting tool I used.

[Twitter](https://support.twitter.com/articles/18906-how-to-delete-a-tweet#freshstart) suggests that I create a new account and simply switch the usernames. Easier said than done.

In order to correct the statistics, what they're basically suggesting is if my username is A with mail id X, I'll have to create a new account B with mail id Y, then I'll have to change the name of A to C and then B to A. Save all the new tweets and then delete the account C. And then, change the new A's mail id from Y to X.
Finally, tweet the saved tweets again and then and only then things are back to the way they were. *sigh*

This sounds like an awful lot of work. Is there any easier way?

I [hear](http://www.jeannetteeatsspaghetti.com/2009/09/how-do-i-spell-problem-solved-u-n-g-u-l.html) there used to be a time when all people had to do was tweet `@charles ungulation`. This hasn't worked for me.